# What do I need to do to fix a 404 error in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I'm new to studying Django and I'm doing a task and I have to display a message with the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/".
But when I search with this url, the error

```
Page not found (404) is displayed
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Using the URLconf defined in project1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, blog/, didn’t match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Could anyone offer me help?

A message chosen by the teacher would have to appear, but I only have the error as a response.

Comment: It looks like you haven't added /blog to your urls file.  Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: I added the "blog" using: def my_view(request):
    print('*****')
    return HttpResponse('Uma mensagem ')


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', my_view),
]                                                                                                                                                        
but when I search by inserting the word "blog" in the url, I get that error

Comment: what is your app name? Did you include your app to the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py?

Comment: Also edit your question to show your urls.py and the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py